# can't change connection string (ODP, Oracle, Linq to Entities)

Tags: ado.net, linq-to-entities, odp.net

I have a App.config connection string that connects me to my database just fine:

```
<add name="SFEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=micahs_poc_dev_server.kci;PASSWORD=kierkegaard;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=KIERKEGAARD&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am using an ODP reference in conjunction with an ADO.NET / Linq to Entities approach.

The trouble comes when I want to connect to a different database (with the same schema) on our network.

```
<add name="SFEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=QA_ETL_TEST_SERVER.COM;PASSWORD=bigshotpassword;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=CoolidgeCalvin&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I just change the name of the server I get this error:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I can actually run several lines of code before it throws an exception:

```
        using (SFEntities ctx1 = new SFEntities())
        {
            var ds = ctx1.Connection.DataSource; // debugger: QA_ETL_TEST_SERVER.COM
            var db = ctx1.Connection.Database;
            var dstate = ctx1.Connection.State;
            var dsite = ctx1.Connection.Site;
            ctx1.Connection.Open();

            SF_CHANGE_ORDER cotest = new SF_CHANGE_ORDER();
            cotest.DELETE_FLAG = "D";
            var result = (from cp in ctx1.SF_CLIENT_PROJECT
                          select cp).ToList();  // <---   error here!
```

I also tried changing the format to this:

```
<add name="SFEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=155.32.75.11)(PORT=65550))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=155.32.75.11)(PORT=65550))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=QA_ETL_TEST_SERVER.COM)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=180)(DELAY=5))));PASSWORD=bigshotpassword;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=CoolidgeCalvin&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Which basically mirrors the TNS entry I have for this server. I still get the 'does not exist' error.

If I make the server name something goofy I get a TNS error saying that server isn't recognized. So I am pretty sure it is picking up the server name I want and checking to see it is there.

I don't think it is a table permissions/creation issue because I can query them just fine on both databases from the same machine with the same credentials (and same TNS file).

[note: I changed the server/user/pw in the strings]

[edit: tried bringing up fiddler, but I didn't see any messages pass through]

Comment: Oracle says that the table does not exist. Take the Sql Query that would be created for your linq Query and run it using ExecuteStoreQuery(). For me it seems like a configuration issue - either you are not connecting to the right database or the database you are connecting to is not identical with the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ... VisualStudio tucks away the schema name in the Model .edmx file. To make it work you have to somehow open the model file (use notepad or search all documents in the project) and manually change the schema name. Boo!